# How to find the index of the first character in a matching regex?

Tags: c++

This is my first question here, I hope that It doesn't sound stupid. So I'm trying to find a way to get the index of the first character from a string that matches the regular expression. I made my research in the `regex` reference in [cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) but I wasn't able to find anything (probably my fault). For anyone that still don't understand what I want to do, let's make a small example, I have the following code:

```
int main () {
  auto re = regex("(\\d+)");
  smatch rematch;
  string str("The num is: 123481");
  regex_search(str, rematch, re);

  if (rematch.size() > 0)
    cout << "It matches!!!\n";
  else
    cout << "It doesn't match!!!\n";
}
```

The following example will match the number in the `str` string. I want to get the index that this match appears. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`position()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/position/) function of [`match_results`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/), so something like that should work:

```
if (rematch.size() > 0)
    cout << "It matches at position " << rematch.position() << "\n";
```